# Move post to different user

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, user-accounts

**Example:** I have a two accounts, one main and one smaller. I create a great post on the mini, and want to move it to the main. Thus, my main can be attributed to the great post without merging the mini to the main.

Is it possible to move some posts (Q or A) from one user to another, without merging everything? (Obviously, with proof that both accounts have permitted this action)

If not, can this feature be considered?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use-case or motivation for having an additional "mini" account?

Comment: @DanBron -- I personally don't have one. However, I know they exist because there must be secondary accounts for SE to have implemented account merging.

Comment: Why the down votes? It wasn't a bad question; the answer to it was merely "no". Do "no"s as answers make the question bad?

Comment: @SirJony [Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), i.e. those who downvoted this question did so because they don't think it should be possible to move the ownership of a single post to another user.

Comment: @dorukayhan -- Oh, got it. Keep the down votes coming! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. We do not support users running multiple accounts past "if it works then ok" and will not implement features for transferring things between accounts.

There are ways to accomplish this for use in cases where things get really, *really* screwed up... Think, someone sat down at your computer and accidentally merged their account into yours or something. You can contact us via the link at the bottom of every page if this ever happens, and we'll... do what we can, if we can. But "just for the heck of it" ain't gonna fly - way too much opportunity for abuse if post transference was conveniently accessible.